# Need help with this proof from Axler's Harmonic Function Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics, cauchy-riemann-equations

A free, legal copy is available [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_13/HFT.pdf).

On pp. 81-82, I have two questions:

1. **Why do the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that all complex derivatives except the $m^{th}$ vanish at the origin?** If anything, this seems to be a consequence of homogeneity: you can only have terms of $m^{th}$ degree if there's a $z^m$ in the complex function for which the polynomial is the real part.
2. **Why does "this" imply that $H_m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the complex linear span of $\{z^m, \overline{z}^m\}$?**  The author shows that $p = cz^m + \overline{cz^m}$ for some constant $c$, so that we would seem not to be free to take *arbitrary* linear combinations of $\{z^m, \overline{z}^m\}$ -- only combinations in which one coefficient is the complex conjugate of the other.

Comment: Please do write out what your question is, rather than just giving a link... Anyway, using complex variables only applies to $\mathbb R^2\approx \mathbb C$, not higher-dimensional spaces. And you can answer the question about which linear combinations of monomials in $z$ and $\overline{z}$ are harmonic directly. It's not "implied" by anything, so much as a directly verifiable truth.

Comment: @paulgarrett I did write out the questions directly, unless I misunderstood your meaning.  I'm just providing the link for reference.

Comment: Well, then I don't understand: the C-R equations do not imply that "all but the $m$th vanish at the origin"... and, anyway, what is "$m$"? What is $H_m$, and $\mathbb R^n$ is relevant how? I'm guessing it may mean "harmonic functions"...? All these things should be clarified in your question, I think.

Comment: The author discusses $H_m(\mathbb{R}^2)$ here which is the complex vector space of degree $m$ harmonic homogenous polynomials in $x,y$; he takes a real element (any general $p=p_1+ip_2, p_1,p_2$ real harmonic and homogenous) and proves that it is $ cz^m + \overline {cz^m}$ using that it is the real part of an analytic function and then by CR imaginary part of that function is also a homogenous polynomial of degree $m$ (once is normalized to be zero at the origin); this implies that a complex polynomial in $H_m$ is indeed a combination of $z^m, \bar z^m$ with arbitrary complex coefficients

Comment: Why don't you just ask Sheldon Axler . He's a member of this site. https://math.stackexchange.com/users/256061/sheldon-axler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let me write $f=p+ig$.
   Since $f$ is holomorphic, you automatically obtain that $\partial_{\overline{z}}f \equiv 0$ (recall that this condition is equivalent to the fact that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations). Now we deal with $\partial_{z}f$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations says
   $$\partial_{x}p=\partial_{y}g \quad \partial_{y}p=-\partial_{x}g.$$
   Thus
   \begin{align*}
       \partial_{z}f&=\frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_{x}f+\frac{1}{i}\partial_{y}f \right) \\
       &=\frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_{x}p+i\partial_{x}g+\frac{1}{i}\partial_{y}p+\partial_{y}g \right) \\
       &=\frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_{x}p-i\partial_{y}p+\frac{1}{i}\partial_{y}p+\partial_{x}p \right) \\
       &=\partial_{x}p+\frac{1}{i}\partial_{y}p
   \end{align*}
   This says that $\partial_{z}f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m-1$ (because the derivative of a homogeneous polynomial is also a homogeneous polynomial). Also,
   \begin{align*}
       \partial_{zz}f&=\frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_{x}\left( \partial_{x}p+\frac{1}{i}\partial_{y}p \right)+\frac{1}{i}\partial_{y}\left( \partial_{x}p+\frac{1}{i}\partial_{y}p \right) \right) \\
       &=\frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_{xx}p+2\frac{1}{i}\partial_{xy}p-\partial_{yy}p \right) 
   \end{align*}
   As before, this says that $\partial_{zz}f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m-2$. Repeating this argument you have that the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$-derivative of $f$ with respect to $z$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m-n$. Since homogeneous polynomial vanishes at $0$, you obtain the first claim. Note that this does not work for the $m^{\mathrm{th}}$-derivative, because you can have the case that the coefficients of your polynomial (which is possibly the last thing left after taking derivatives) do not sum zero.
2. I think you are right. Until now you have $f=cz^{m}$. Then
   $$p=\operatorname{Re}(f)=\frac{cz^{m}+\overline{cz^{m}}}{2}.$$
   I think that maybe the authors made some abuse of the notation with the constants in this case... Thus, the authors proved that $$H_{m}(\mathbb{R}^{2}) \subset \{ dz^{m}+\overline{dz^{m}};d \in \mathbb{C}\}.$$
   The other inclusion is clear. Therefore, you only have that
   $$H_{m}(\mathbb{R}^{2})= \{ dz^{m}+\overline{dz^{m}};d \in \mathbb{C}\}, \qquad  (*)$$
   which is different to have the equality with $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{C}}\{z^{m},\overline{z^{m}}\}$. I think that this was just a little error writing what they had in mind, because it makes sense to obtain (*) due to the "symmetry" of the Fourier coefficients: $a_{m}=\overline{a_{-m}}$.